# How Do I Change the Mood of the Slot Machines?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In Serendipity the girl next to the slot machine will tell you the "mood" of the machine so that you can tell if playing it will be a waste of time. It seems to only perform *decently* if it's "on fire" or "hot".

I've tried exiting to the Historia Crux and coming back into the zone, but I can't seem to really get a much better mood. Is this dependent on something else in the game? Time passed perhaps? Or am I just getting unlucky with this moody machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I am assuming you are playing slots for the Lucky Coin fragment and not because you like it (because I personally found it to be a bore and a chore). This is what I did.

I always started with at least 5000 coins. I walked up to the lady that tells you the mood and saved my game. If she doesn't say something like, "It's like a warm summers day" or the machine is "On Fire" I would just quit to the main menu and load up my save again. Eventually she said the above and I started my grind, thus begins the boring part.

I used a small piece of tape to keep the button down to keep the machine chuggin' along (watching a movie while it was running :P). Hopefully you will hit the Jackpot, which will prompt the machine to enter Overbreak mode (I think this is what it was called...). In Overbreak mode you have something like ten times the chance of hitting the jackpot and bring in 5,000 coins per win.

If you can make it to Overbreak mode you should get the achievement for 10,000 coins, if you don't already have it, and get your Lucky Coin fragment.

If you don't get it and run out of coins, don't panic... just reload your game and try again!

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of how to cheat the slots, since it is so pointless and boring. I guess all I really needed here was how to get a different mood for the machine.

Comment: @Yuck Right on. There might be a better or faster way than reloading your save. But that is what I found worked for me.

Comment: @Yuck My wife just told me that she thinks simply walking out of the building and back in can trigger a change.

Comment: I may try that later - but your suggestion to reload a save definitely resets it. I got "on fire" now and happily taped down my L1.

Comment: @Yuck Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is simply get in the machine and back out. Go and talk to her and she will have a new mood for the machine. This is the fastest way that I found but she has never had a bad mood for me - that might be because I don't play slots that much though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have save data from XIII, the mood of the slots are always either fire or summer day. There is an item called an eternal crystal (I think) in your key items that you get from XIII save data.